# Gridview not binding and showing datas from my database

Tags: c#, asp.net

well, I've done everything on my behalf just to solve this problem. i'm trying to print the data from my database using grid view in asp.net using c# codes. can anyone tell me whats wrong and how to improve my codes. thank you.

```
   using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            constructor var = new constructor();
            con.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name,username,contact_number,address,email FROM user_tbl WHERE user_type='2'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader1.Close();

            try
            {                   
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblresult.Text = "ERROR>>" + ex.Message + "!";
            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                sql = null;

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fill the DataSet with data like this :

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "TableName");
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["TableName"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thank you sir. it worked like magic. hehe. thank you very much. :)

Comment: sir, i sent you a private message on facebook. i would be glad to know your thoughts on my message. thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning an empty `DataSet` to your `DataSource`, without filling the results of your `DataReader` into the `DataSet/DataTable`.

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(""))
{
    con.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT first_name,last_name,username,contact_number,address,email FROM user_tbl WHERE user_type='2'";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(reader1);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt ;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblresult.Text = "ERROR>>" + ex.Message + "!";
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        sql = null;

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but im still getting the same error

Comment: One small fix, sorry for that. Check the updated answer now.